# Connection string error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on MVC3 project which have two projects in solution. First for MVC Model, View and Controller and second for Data Access (DAL). In DAL project Ian using Entity Framework 4 for data access. I am using ASP.NET Membership for user authentication. Connection string in both projects are quite same but when a user trying to login an error occur **System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'metadata'**. Same connection string is working for rest of project. I can fetch data and display quite fine. But while login this error occurs. Please tell either my connection string is faulty or i need special connection string for Membership provider? Or any solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set your Entity Framework's Serialization Mode to "Unidirectional"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [SqlMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx) you need to give an [ordinary connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008#p1). You have given it an EntityConnection. So create a new connection string in your web.config and configure that for the membership provider.